# Last visited pages history with django

Tags: django

I'm a newbie with django and working on a project where I need to display registered user's last visited pages on their profile page. I have achieved that within my extended user class by adding a new many2many field to my main object which I want to keep history for. In my view, whenever a member makes a request I add the object to member's history. But this doesn't give me the result that I want. Items are not ordered and if user is not logged in it gives User DoesNotExist error. I know there is a better way then this but I could't find it. Probably I'm not on the correct way. I appreciate any help or ideas.

```
class myObjectView(View):
    model = myObject
    template_name = 'app/myobject_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        cat = Category.objects.all()
        sec = Section.objects.all()
        self.item = myObject.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs[u'slug'])
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

        if user.is_authenticated():
            if self.item in user.member.history.all():
                user.member.history.remove(self.item)
                user.member.history.add(self.item)
                user.save()
            else:
                user.member.history.add(self.item)
                user.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach has drawbacks but is not a bad one if you need long term persistance.

You could easily add an `ordering` field in your m2m through table (look at docs) to add some sense of ordering. You could also order your m2m through table by its PK, as large PK values would mean newer entries given your current code of removing items and adding them again.

```
ordered_item_history = (user.member.history.through.objects
    .filter(user=user, myObject=self.item)
    .order_by('pk').values_list('myObject', flat=True))
```

That said the easiest way to do something like this is in the session.

```
request.session.setdefault('history', []).append(myObj)
request.session.modified = True
```

Now in any view, you can access this ever-growing list of object history via `request.session['history']`. Modify as necessary to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: If the display of history is required at next login or for auditing, you'll need to store it in the database (my preference would be to store it in some external k/v store).

Comment: Thanks Yuji, now it's clear. Now my problem is with `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` If user is not logged in I got DoesNotExist error. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: You don't need the user if you use sessions. If you want to use your History m2m method, you will want to add an FK to the django Session table, then use that if users are not logged in.

Comment: Well, I put it in try except blog. looks like working. Thanks for the help.